# include only *.pyc files in python wheel

Tags: python-3.x, python-wheel, egg

How can I include only *.pyc files in a python wheel?
When creating eggs, it used to be possible to run
`python setup.py bdist_egg --exclude-source-files`

Given that eggs have been [replaced by wheels](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/wheel-vs-egg/), how would I reproduce a similar result?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it, but it looks like [pyc-wheel](https://pyc-wheel.readthedocs.io) does precisely that.